# Angular Local Storage Delete Not Removing item

Tags: java, angular, typescript, local-storage, crud

Hello I am learning angular and I'm working on a todo app that stores to local storage. Getting the local storage to remove a single item as well as editing an item has been a challenge and I've not found many good resources.

Right now it looks like its removing the entire array and I'm not sure why. Hopefully Ive included the proper details.

This is is my delete/remove in the CRUD task

```
deleteTask(task : Task) {
    localStorage.removeItem(this.taskKey)
  }
```

This is the delete task in the componant

```
  deleteTask(idx: number) {
    this.taskService.deleteTask(new Task(this.addTaskValue))
    if( idx >= 0) {
      this.taskArr.splice(idx, 1);
    }
  }
```

Other Details from the componant

```
  taskArr: Task[]; 

  public addTaskValue: string = '';

  constructor(private taskService: TaskService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addTaskValue = '';

    this.taskArr = this.taskService.getAllTasks();


    }
```

[Local Storage Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pzLu.png)

I've tried to just use the splice out in the deleteTask but that only removed it from the screen and not the local storage. Ive tried a bunch of other things as well but cant recall them all in detail.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your local storage? I wondering if you are using the right `key`.

Comment: Just added it to the original post as a link, thanks!

Comment: When you call `localStorage.removeItem(this.taskKey)`, how do you expect it to know which index it should delete? Aside from that, localStorage only stores strings, so it does not have a concept of arrays. You will need to compute the new array in javascript (ie remove the one todo) and then store this new array as a string, e.g. with `localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos))`

Comment: your right, I think im doing that with ```localStorage.setItem(this.taskKey, JSON.stringify(cache) )``` further up

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, you provided. I don't see a logic where the `taskKey` is even being set. I would add some console statements to see if you're even getting the right string in `this.taskKey`.

```
deleteTask(task : Task) {
    console.log(this.taskKey); // check if this value is "tasks"
    localStorage.removeItem(this.taskKey)
}
```

Essentially it needs to boil down to this.

```
localstorage.removeItem('tasks').
```

[image]

Comment: taskKey is being set earlier in the task.service as ``` taskKey = 'tasks' ```

Comment: ok. can you post a stackblize? Somehow I think it's probably not passed into the delete function. maybe you are creating a new Task object in the deleteTask function?